# No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds after pointing to external postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, airflow, gunicorn, airflow-webserver

I am deploying airflow latest release using Docker, everything works fine until I point the database to an external Postgres Database. As soon as the database is pointed to an external database the webserver container doesn't get up.

The release is from apache/airflow:latest

The logs says the following

**No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds**

[image]

What am I missing here ?

Comment: did you check the webserver container log?

Comment: Yes, its in the screenshot

Comment: This error comes when the number of workers running does not match the expected number of workers for a period of time. check the number of workers in airflow.cfg file, try reducing it to a smaller number, probably 1.

Comment: @anshul_cached were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: It still not working for me, using solution from @AvnishSingh

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this issue as well.

Comment: @anshul_cached, try increasing the timeout for the master worker and reducing the number of workers. You can check [this issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10964) on github as well